# CRM 2011 - Email Router and Multiple Contacts with Same Email address

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, email

We use Email Router in our on premise CRM 2011 system. We have multiple contacts with the same email address and while that is a problem that we hope to fix as part of an upgrade, we have another issue here.

Let us assume I have more than one contact (Contact 1: John Reese and Contact 2: Not John Reese) with the same email address of John.Reese@gmail.com.

I now send an email from my email address which is Harrison.Ford@gmail.com to a particular queue's email address or user's email address. I add John.Reese@gmail.com in the CC field.

The email record gets created in CRM but if I open the Email record in CRM, I find that it has populated the CC field with LookUps to both Contact 1 and Contact 2. We do not want that to happen. We simply want the email record to have the CC field unresolved (i.e, just have the text John.Reese@gmail.com and not auto resolve it ALL contacts and organizations which have the email address).

I have tried identifying if there is a Plugin which does this and I am afraid I could not find any. :-(

Questions:

1. Is this the email router and associated rules which are doing this or is there a plugin lurking behind the scenes which is doing this?
2. If we were to send an email from the address John.Reese@gmail.com, it doesn't happen populate the From field with both the Contacts, instead it just leaves it as unresolved. So, where can I find the email router rules and replicate the functionality which is currently in place for the From field to the CC field as well?

Answer (score 0):

All email addresses will be stored in EmailSearchBase table in CRM database for each record with email address + entity type & the email recipients will be resolved from here for each entry in this table like contact, lead, etc. This is what you are referring as rule.

This database table will have one record for dupe contacts also. You have to clean the data using duplicate detection & enforce detection rule. Merge the contacts will solve the issue too.

But you have to run update statements for these dupe records in Emailsearchbase also. Like updating John.Reese@gmail.com email id into John.Reese_2@gmail.com to keep the dupe contact (Not John Reese) but just avoiding him in email recipients list (auto resolving).

This is not documented or least documented, but you can explore & clean up this entity.